# Axis2 with XMLBeans data binding - Problem with a java client generated from a XSD schema with anyType

Tags: java, xsd, apache-axis, xmlbeans

I have generated a client using Axis2 framework with XMLBeans as the data binding method.
The XSD schema is the following:
`<xsd:schema>

    <xsd:element name="profile" type="anyType"/>

    </xsd:schema>`

The java object generated which takes part of the SOAP request contains getter and setter methods that allow to get and set the profile. Here is the method signature:
    `requestDocument.setProfile(XmlObject profile);`

The problem is that even if that I have to pass several nodes as the profile and not a valid XML document, but XMLObject expects a XML document with a root node.

I need to pass:
     `<accounts></accounts>

     <payees></payees>`

Actually, the service I use expects those nodes but did not constrains them in the schema. Thus, I can't add another root node because even if the service won't throw any exceptions, the profile won't be usable.

XMLBeans already adds the underlying XML tree, I mean the profile node in the request document. Thus, I can't use it as a root node. if I add a root node, the following XML will be created
    `<profile>
    <profile></profile>
    </profile>`

And I want the document be formatted as follow:
    `<profile>

    <accounts></accounts>
    <payees></payees>

    </profile>`

I prefer not modifying the schema of the service. I would want to know if there is a way with Axis2/XMLBeans to tackle this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find a solution that is probably a workaround and not the clean way it should be done. 
Instead of setting the profile with an `XMLObject` as follow:
`requestDocument.setProfile(XmlObject profile);`
I used `org.w3c.dom.Node` object to create the profile content. See below:
1. Create the elements `org.w3c.dom.Element` to be added to the profile:
`Element accountsElt = profileDocument.createElement("accounts");`
`Element payeesElt = profileDocument.createElement("payees");`
2. Create an empty profile in the document to be send to the service, note that the object is auto generated:
`requestDocument.addNewProfile();`
3. Get the empty profile and add children to its root node:
`requestDocument.getProfile().getDomNode().appendChild(accountsElt);`
`requestDocument.getProfile().getDomNode().appendChild(payeesElt);`

I hope it helps.